# Perl to Input lines from CSV into system command variable

Tags: perl

I'm new to coding, but I want this script to parse the CSV file and input it into the command below where it says node=nodename. I need the command to run for each node that is in the CSV file.
Can this be done with the current system command?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

# make nodes inactive
   my $inputfile = "/home/nmis/InactiveNodes.csv";
   open(INPUT,'<',$inputfile) or die $!;
   my @data = <INPUT>;
   system ("/usr/local/nmis9/admin/node_admin.pl act=set **node=nodename** 
   entry.activated.NMIS=0 entry.activated.opConfig=0 entry.activated.opEvents=0 &");
```

Comment: You need a loop around the `system()` call. Each iteration will pass a new value for the node name. Please show an example of the input file `InactiveNodes.csv`

Comment: Please find a time to read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your question does not include a sample of input data -- it is a critical piece for processing data.

Comment: the sample is just a node name nothing more. so it could be just "test" for example and then the next line in the csv is test2 etc its literally just one column

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you could read the CSV file and extract node names to be passed to the `node_admin.pl` script:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

my $inputfile = "/home/nmis/InactiveNodes.csv";
open(my $INPUT, '<', $inputfile) or die "Could not open $inputfile: $!";
while( my $line = <$INPUT> ) {
    chomp $line;
    my @fields = split ",", $line;
    my $node = $fields[1];
    system ("/usr/local/nmis9/admin/node_admin.pl act=set node=$node"
            . " entry.activated.NMIS=0 entry.activated.opConfig=0 "
            . " entry.activated.opEvents=0 &");
}
close $INPUT;
```

Comment: Thanks Hakon, this is failing for me on line 12,  Use of uninitialized value $node in concatenation (.) or string at ./SetNodesInactive.pl line 12, <$INPUT> line 1. This may be due to my CSV only contain one column of nodes? I just need the script to read line and input it into the system command.

Comment: If there is only one field per line, you could try using `$fields[0]` instead of `$fields[1]`

Comment: That worked! Thanks, i will need to work on getting this to loop through the file now as it only pulls from the first field of the file in the column